# Error initializing QueryElevationComponent . Boosting query defined twice for query

Tags: solr, lucene

I Have implemented my own custom Solr filter and if I try to add this filter to the index and query analyzer I get this error:

> Error CREATEing SolrCore 'itemsCore': Unable to create core [itemsCore] Caused by: Boosting query defined twice for query: 'aciclovir' (.

Adding the filter just to the index analyzer works.

Its just a custom decomposition filter in which I override decompose method.

**UPDATE**

Elevation component has this tag

```
<query text="aciclovir">
    <doc id="905093" />
  </query>
```

My solr config for the elevator part.

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" >
  <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">keyword_text</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate_${solr.core.name}.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>
```

Schema config for this filed:

```
<fieldType name="keyword_text" class="solr.TextField"
    positionIncrementGap="1000" omitNorms="true" 
    omitTermFreqAndPositions="true">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\|" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter
                class="solr.custom.filter.CustomDecompositionFilterFactory"
                dictionary="lang/germanwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="1" max="100" />
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" />
        </analyzer>
        
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="\$" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"
                words="lang/stopwords_de.txt" format="snowball" />

            <filter
                class="solr.custom.filter.CustomDecompositionFilterFactory"
                dictionary="lang/germanwords.txt" />
                
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory" />
            <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="4" />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

Comment: could you share your elevation component config?

Comment: @Mysterion added elevation component

Comment: you do not have anything else in elevate.xml?

Comment: There is nothing else.

Comment: that's strange, could you as well provide solrconfig part for searchComponent for elevator and for requestHandler /elevate?

Comment: @Mysterion added configs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156666/discussion-between-mysterion-and-user2960896).